# How do I wire my 4 way switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

At the bottom is the stairs is the first 3 way switch in this circuit - it doesn’t need to be messed with because it was never changed and works good.
Then go up the stairs a little where a 4 way switch needs to be wired.
The wires I have on that one to hook up are 2 white, 2 red and the blacks inside are wired nutted together.
Then in between this switch is the 1st light with power source which goes to another light, then it stops at the last final 3 way switch.
So how, do I wire my 4 way?
I could get pictures if you need. Btw we originally replaced it and must of wired it wrong because when one switch is off another won’t turn light on![image][image]

Comment: Punctuation is your friend. Don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: I am willing to help, but I can't make any sense of this.  Meet me halfway and [edit] your question so it is clearly stated and understandable.

Comment: Done all fixed punctuated and makes sense

Comment: Can you post pictures please?

Comment: much better :) +1

Answer (score 4):

- Unhook all 4 conductors.
- Identify 2 conductors *that are in the same cable*.  Necessarily, one will be white and the other red.   This pair will be a pair of *travelers*.
- While we're here, it's illegal to use a white wire this way without marking it with black or a color. Also, nothing tells you that this white is associated with that red.  I suggest marking both the red wire and the white wire with electrical tape of the same color, e.g. yellow.  You can mark them the same color because both wires do the same thing and are interchangeable.
- Anyway, these two *travelers* go on the **Brass** terminals of the switch.
- One pair of travelers will remain, also white and red.
- Same thing, mark them so the white is tagged a color and also to associate them with each other.
- This set of travelers goes on the **Black** terminals.

How did I know? I just know how 3-way/4-way circuits work.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thx it worked well how did you know how

Comment: What is the function of the 4 way switch.  It seems to be a double pole single throw switch, which is basically an on-off switch. Why use DPST rather than another 3 way?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC it's hard to see from the drawing but look at the gray current path and fifth terminal.  In practice it's a **reversing switch**.  It wires AX and BY... Or AY and BX.  It can be made by taking a DPDT and connecting the non-common terminals with an X.

Comment: What is the function of the DPDT switch? Why use a reversing switch with a light. (I could see a motor.)

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC because of the way travelers work. In a 3-way system, either one traveler or the other is energized. A 3/4 way switch alters which traveler is selected.  The 4-way switch, being in the middle, must exchange travelers.